# Angular 2 strings remain undefined on first iteration

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, angular

I'm trying to fetch an object from the server via http.get and it works but the strings remain undefined on the first iteration.
[The full object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ycz2.jpg)

The integers are ok, the problem is only with the strings.

```
        this.http.get("/Home/getRoom", { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(q => {
    this.timecount = q.timeperquestion; this.player1id = JSON.stringify(q.player1id); this.player2id = q.player2id; }, err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Complete'));
```

after the first iteration of the function the strings are shown.

EDIT:

this is the class:

```
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
public answered = false;
public title = "loading question...";
public options = [];
public correctAnswer = false;
public working = false;
public timecount=15;
public timer;
public roomID;
public player1id;
public player2id;

constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, private Ref: changeDetectorRef) {


}


nextQuestion() {

    this.working = true;
    this.answered = false;
    this.title = "loading question...";
    this.options = [];
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('If-Modified-Since', 'Mon, 27 Mar 1972 00:00:00 GMT');
    this.http.get("/Home/getRoom", { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(q => {
    this.timecount = q.timeperquestion;
    this.player1id = JSON.stringify(q.player1id);
    this.Ref.detectChanges();
    },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log('Complete'));
```

EDIT 2:
Ok it seems like everything is ok with the strings, when I try to display it with {{player1id}} it shows the right value even on the first iteration.
The "problem" is only with console.log(player1id) that i used to check the string with, it works only after one iteration.
Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: What are the `headers` defined as, and can you share the class that this is being called in? Not enough information to provide a relevant answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the mess and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could force the change detection to run using the `ChangeDetectorRef` class. Inject it and call its `detectChanges` method:

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef:changeDetectorRef) {
}

someMethod() {
  this.http.get("/Home/getRoom", { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(q => {
    this.timecount = q.timeperquestion;
    this.player1id = JSON.stringify(q.player1id);
    this.player2id = q.player2id;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  },
  err => console.error(err),
  () => console.log('Complete'));
}
```

Comment: Isn't forcing a `detectChanges` a poor practice?

Comment: Yes agreed! It should work without this but in this case it seems required for some reasons...

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined(…)

Comment: When you inject into your component, I see a typo. It should be: `constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, private Ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {` instead of `constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, private Ref: changeDetectorRef) {` (`changeDetectorRef` -> `ChangeDetectorRef`).

Comment: Same.. when I try   constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http, @Inject(ChangeDetectorRef) private Ref: ChangeDetectorRef) (I'm not sure if that's how you inject more than one item) I'm getting EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for AppComponent(@Inject(Http), @Inject(undefined)). Make sure they all have valid type or annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the properties are `undefined` is due to the fact that they are actually *not* defined. Simply set them to an empty string `= ""` or declare them as a `: string` like this:

```
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   public player1id: string;
   public player2id = ""; // I usually prefer this as it is assigned a value
   // Omitted for brevity...
}
```

In **TypeScript** you should either declare the type you're intending to use or assign it such that it is inferred. Otherwise you're kind of missing out on all the glory of **TypeScript**.

Comment: I already tried that, but the problem is the values remain empty on the first iteration..

Comment: Can you place this in a plunker, there must be something else going on here that can be explained reasonably. The use of the `detectChanges` should not be required.